# Ordered Column's cell is not highlighted in the JQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables, highlight, columnsorting

When I select a row, the cells of the ordered columns are not being highlighted as you can see below. For example, in my code

```
  "order": [[0,"desc"],[ 1, "desc" ],[ 7, "desc" ]],
```

the 7. index column is Created Date and when I click a row, it is not highlighted (as column 0 and 1)

[image]

0, 1 and 7th index columns's cells cannot be selected and if I remove those indexes from order : [] then they are selectable.

[image]

and when I click a column's header to sort, this cell directly becomes unhighlighted. As I understand, ordered columns cannot be highlighted. How can I make the column 7 highlighted when I select a row?

Update:

I opened the source code and you can see the selected row's html code.

[image]

as can be seen, the ordered columns have class names. when I delete the class, everything is OK. so I do not want to change the class or css. is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm suspecting the issue is in the way you decorate selected rows. If you happen to have your `selected` class assigned to `<td>` rather than `<tr>` with some improper selector, the issue like that might raise.

To fix that problem, make sure `selected` class is assigned to `<tr>` upon selection.

Comment: thank you for the answer.I've updated the question by considering your answer.

Comment: Do you use DataTables select extension or you implement that feature on your own? If latter is the case, please, share corresponding code. May you also share your CSS part that is used to decorate selected rows (cells)?

Comment: I do not use neither an extension nor my own css. I've opened plugins.min.css and find out the class_3 and removed the background color, it worked.. but I am looking for kind of a configuration that disables this thing.

Comment: Could you make it a bit clearer for me: what exactly you wanted to achieve by modifying plugins.min.css ? Can you show wider code context, as it is still not clear for me how exactly you make your *selected* rows actually selected.

Comment: le.dataTable th.sorting_3{background:#fbfcfd!important}.paging_bootstrap_extended{margin:5px 0 0!important;  for example here, when I delete the color code or 'important' then the my selected row (by mouse) highlighted. I think I will just deleted important keyword and its fine. thank you